# How to avoid read() from hanging in the following situation?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, zombie-process

I have some code that forks a third-party application and redirects its standard output to the parent process, roughly as follows (no error handling here for brevity):

```c
char* args[] = {"/path/to/3rd/party/binary", "with", "args", NULL};

int fds[2];
pipe2(fds, O_CLOEXEC);

pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{
    dup2(fds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    execvp(args[0], args);
    _exit(1);
}
else
{
    close(fds[1]);

    char buf[1024];
    int bytes_read;
    while ((bytes_read = read(fds[0], buf, sizeof buf - 1)) > 0)
    {
        buf[bytes_read] = '\0';
        printf("%s", buf);
    }

    close(fds[0]);
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
}
```

I have no code for the third-party application, it is a proprietary binary. When running the third-party application in a terminal with the same arguments as used in the code above, it eventually finishes. However, when forking the third-party binary using the code above, it does not finish, but becomes a zombie process, and the code above hangs on the `read()` call.

The third-party binary that is forked itself forks two daemon processes (again, proprietary binaries I do not control), which I think is causing the problem here. The forked daemon processes will have a copy of the duplicated file descriptor, preventing the `read()` from finishing. Indeed, in case the `dup2()` call is replaced with:

```
dup3(fds[1], STDOUT_FILENO, O_CLOEXEC);
```

the child process finishes, but there is no output redirection to the parent process of course. Also, when the code above is modified to not do any output redirection to the parent over a pipe, the child process finishes correctly.

Is it possible to somehow prevent this hang on the `read()` call in this situation, or do I need to resort to some form of non-blocking I/O?

Update; using a simple `popen()` suffers from the same problem.

(Follow-up from: [read() hangs on zombie process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556070/read-hangs-on-zombie-process))

Comment: An awful situation to be in. I'm not aware of any way (short of attaching a debugger) to prevent an unmodifiable application from leaking a FD. How about reading with a timeout and adding an angry comment?

Comment: @thatotherguy, I am still hoping to avoid that :) A typical shell is able to handle this situation, so one last resort is to dig through some shell code to see what they do..

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to ignore SIGCHLD? It's your responsibility to reap the zombie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specifically ignore SIGCHLD. It's your responsibility to reap the zombie, but you can't do it when blocked in `read`. If you call `read` after the `SIGCHLD` has been swallowed, you'll stay in `read` forever.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. For future reference, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40601337/what-is-the-use-of-ignoring-sigchld-signal-with-sigaction2